# How do I figure out who is using sql server

Tags: sql-server, audit

I asked asked this question yesterday but it disappeared :(. Anyway, I have a sql server that I want to decomission and need to figure out who is relying on it. There could be a bunch of tools and users relying on it. Other than a sql trace to track log in information, what is the best way to find out as much as I can about the clients relying on the box? I want to know more than just the sql log in info, I want to know which client machines, the IPs, the credentials and details about the specific different applications. If there is one box with more than one application running (for example), I need to know these are two apps that may be passing the same credentials. Help?

Comment: Duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/112089/decommissioning-how-to-list-clients-applications-depending-on-my-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

```
show processlist;
```

will show you who is currently connected and all there connection details but it will only show you the connections at the time you run the command and not a history.

Comment: and to kill of a process just use kill {Id}; from that query

Comment: that's mysql not sql server

Answer (score 0):

It didn't get lost, it looks like you're using a different username to post these two questions
[Decommissioning: how to list clients/applications depending on my SQL Server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/112089/decommissioning-how-to-list-clients-applications-depending-on-my-sql-server)

Also - since you added a new requirement in this question that wasn't in the first - I don't think you will be able to tell if a single client machine is using two different applications that connect using the same SQL login. You may see multiple connections, but you won't necessarily know if that's from a single application or multiple.